# rails has_many relation of parent not updated after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Simplified code for Rails 5.2.

A very simple `Base` class that adds up some value of its Items.

```rb
class Base < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items

  def values
    children.map(&:value).sum
  end
end
```

The `Item` class which modifies itself:

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: :base

  def increment
    puts parent.values # == 0
    self.value = 10
    save!
    puts parent.values # == 0 #???
  end
end
```

when calling `some_item.increment` I'd expect the second `parent.values` to return 10, but it doesn'T.
On the next call it does return 10, somehow this is cached for the first call.

Is there some hidden caching mechanism, or is `save!` delaying the change?

Comment: I think it has already loaded the parent object into memory with your first line - try reloading the instance: `save!; parent.reload!; puts parent.values`

Comment: @Mark yes, this does work. I think what's happening, is that the `has_many`-`belongs_to` relation is not reusing the item. `Base` get the same item again from the DB and retain a different object, so the object calling `save!` is not the same one from `base`. Isn't there a way to tell base to reuse the same object? (instead of creating a new one from the DB)

Comment: I don't believe so :( https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching - I've always had to manually reload in specs / code when needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must reload the parent object using `reload!`

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: :base

  def increment
    puts parent.values # == 0
    self.value = 10
    save!
    parent.reload!
    puts parent.values
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this is what @Mark said. It looks like an overkill having to reload everything. A very confusing but more effective approach would be to let the item iterate over the parent to find the reference to itself and update and save that object. But that's convoluted...